# How to get the view as shown below?

Tags: android, css, html, cordova

hi i am developing an android application using phonegap and i have come across an UI which looks something like as show in the picture

[image]

here in image there is a wall to which the information of different users are wrapped around it. I want to get something in that way can anyone give me an idea how to get this kind of UI using html and css.I hope i'm able to explain what i need sorry if my question is not clear. Thank you.

Comment: yah previously the UI was different but now this is what exactly i want.I want some thing of this kind i'm not able to find it can u help me?

Comment: You might want to remove the previous question. this one is much clearer (and don't post duplicates)

Comment: its an background image or use an divider image with white background.

Comment: @PadmaKumar it's not a background image

Comment: what site is this? Perhaps someone with Firebug or something similar  (Like me) is interested in that to see how it works and provide the answer.

Comment: a URL? Please? I want to know how this is done too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-practical-css-shapes/.

Although this is just for one side, I think it is not so hard to get it working for the right side too.

EDIT:

I got it working for both sides:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  

<html lang="en">  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>CSS Shapes</title>  
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {  
            background: #666;  
            margin: auto;  
            width: 500px;  
            height: 700px;  
            padding-top: 30px;  
            font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;  
        }  

        h1 {  
            background: #e3e3e3;
            border-top-left-radius:3px;
            border-top-right-radius:3px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #c8c8c8);  
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottombottom, from(#e3e3e3), to(#c8c8c8));  
            padding: 10px 20px;  
            margin-left: -20px;  
            margin-top: 0;  
            position: relative;  
            width: 100%;  

            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;  
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;  
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;  

            color: #454545;  
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;  
        }  

        .arrow {  
            width: 0; height: 0;  
            line-height: 0;  
            border-left: 20px solid transparent;  
            border-top: 10px solid #c8c8c8;  
            top: 104%;  
            left: 0;  
            position: absolute;  
        }  
        .rightArrow {
            width: 0; height: 0;  
            line-height: 0;  
            border-right: 20px solid transparent;  
            border-top: 10px solid #c8c8c8;  
            top: 104%;  
            left: 100%;  
            margin-left:-20px;
            position: absolute;  
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>  
        <style>  
            .arrow { top: 100%; }  
        </style>  
    <![endif]-->  

</head>  
<body>  
     <div id="container">  

        <h1> My Heading <span class="arrow"></span> <span class="rightArrow"></span></h1>  

    </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

well as i have mentioned earlier that css3 is very powerful, just go through these[demos](http://webdesignerwall.com/trends/47-amazing-css3-animation-demos) to check what all can be achieved by it. most of this can be done in phonegap also as phonegap works well with  css3. also jquery page transitions will also help  a lot.

Comment: Thank you i will go through those demo's.

Comment: He should not accept this since it does not actually answer the question. (But: amazing these demo's! Thanks!)